# How to make a new list containing the previous

Tags: python

I am trying to make a new list from:

```
t1=['Jon','Sali','Sara']
t2=[7,12,23]
```

How do I make a new list (t3) which contain the previous lists elements arranged as name, then age, like:

```
t3=['Jon',7]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to create the expected pairs :

```
>>> t1=['Jon','Sali','Sara']
>>> t2=[7,12,23]
>>> zip(t1,t2)
[('Jon', 7), ('Sali', 12), ('Sara', 23)]
```

And if you just want list use `map` to convert the tuples to list :

```
>>> l=map(list,zip(t1,t2))
[['Jon', 7], ['Sali', 12], ['Sara', 23]]
```

Then you'll have all the `(name,age)` pairs within one list and you can access to them with indexing :

```
>>> l[0]
['Jon', 7]
```

Or you can create a dictionary :

```
>>> d={'t{}'.format(i):(k,v) for i,(k,v) in enumerate(zip(t1,t2))}
>>> d['t0']
('Jon', 7)
```

Comment: thank for helping me .
but I've tried the code zip and didn't work :

python shows me this message
<zip object at 0x02D69148>

Comment: Then I suppose you use Python 3. Use this: [z for z in map(list, zip(t1, t2))] gives you [['Jon', 7], ['Sali', 12], ['Sara', 23]]

Comment: @Mari as Gergely Sipkai says you are using python 3 an in python 3 `zip` return an iteratorso use `list` to convert your result to list `>>> list(zip(t1,t2))
[('Jon', 7), ('Sali', 12), ('Sara', 23)]
`

Comment: sorry , I wrote that I use python 3 but the question has been modified

Comment: @Mari OK! so what about the accepting the answer ? ;)